# what's the error code "123" of the wget means

Tags: linux, bash, shell

when i use the gun wget (version 1.13) to fetch a file list like this:

```
cat url.txt | xargs wget -c -P ../data/
```

Then, I get the exit code 123, what does it means?

thx:)

Comment: what does url.txt look like? Are there maybe blanks in the lines?

Comment: @Zane no, Icheck all the urls in the file, there is no blanks.

Answer (score 5):

`123` is an exit code from `xargs` - one or more invocation of the command failed with an error code in the range 1-125. It means your `wget` command failed, but doesn't tell you why.

Comment: but how can i find out the real problem about the failed command? thx

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this just to see the lines that pose a problem :

```
while read; do wget -c -P ../data/ "$REPLY"; done < url.txt
```